# Acer W500 touchscreen events

Tags: unity, gnome, acer, touchscreen

I have very strange behavior of my touchscreen 
In gnome shell or unity I am unable to click with it on unity panel or gnome shell interface.
But i can iteract with gtk+ windows, if i open gnome shell with hardware button all gnome shell interface became clickable, until I close it/

with xev and xinput utilities I found that in xev buttonpress event is not generated by touchscreen but in xinput all events showed correctly
I post my problem in many places but no answer for now

may be not direct answer, but directions how to find the exact source of the problem will be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with my WeTab. I can offer you only a partially solution.

At first you have to install the eGalax-driver for your touchscreen.
You can download it [here](https://www.eeti.com/drivers_Linux.html)
After that you have to open /etc/eGTouchL.ini with Gedit and change "report mode" from "1" to "2".
That allows you to click correctly at everything but disables holding of the "button", which is needed for selecting multiple files or scrolling down on pages.

If you don´t change the configuration of the driver you could still use the starter with creating a right click with holding the finger at the icons. The context menu still appears and works without problems.

While searching for this bug I came to this [bugreport](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1099289) which seams very similar. Somewhere in the comments someone wrote about a patch for the x-server but I have no idea if it works or how to use it.

Edit: Are you using 13.04? In a test with a live stick with 12.10 everything works normal.